# International Telephone Input with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a input phone with AngularJS as you can see on [this picture](https://goo.gl/7ylvF9).

I tried :

- I tried using ng-option, but I can't insert image to dropdown list.
- I tried [this solution](http://goo.gl/NoiZDv) but this didn't work neither.

How can I insert image to ng-option? I'm new to AngularJS.

```html
   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="myForm">
      <label for="mySelect">Make a choice:</label>
      <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
           ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id"
           ng-model="data.selectedOption">A</select>
       <input type="text" name="number" value="{{data.selectedOption.macode}}">
    </form>
```

This is js file

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp', [])

 myApp.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

   $scope.data = {
    availableOptions: [
      {id: '1', name: 'VIET NAM', macode:'+84'},
      {id: '2', name: 'AMERICAN',macode:'+85'},
      {id: '3', name: 'CANADA',macode:'+86'}
    ],
    selectedOption: {id: '3', name: 'Option C',macode:'+86'} //This sets the default value of the select in the ui
    };
    code:'+84';
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that @brianlmerritt

Comment: create the HTML that will show the picture, and then us ng-repeat to generate that html automatically from your controller. Also remember to use `ng-src="{{urlToPhoto}}"` - note deleted earlier comment that missed the quotes.